# OpenCV2 skin segmentation with back projection

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect human skin in the video feed from my webcam using back projection. I use one of OpenCV's haar cascade classifiers to detect the face, and use a region of the forehead to generate a histogram for back projection to detect other areas of the skin. Below is the result I have so far. The result below is the best I've had so far and it still has a lot of noise. I would like to have the whole face (and all other skin areas detected) to be one large connected component so I can draw a contour around that area as the detected skin. I have no idea how to continue and I would be very grateful if anyone could help with suggestions, code snippets, etc.

Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


MatND getHistogram(Mat image);

int lowThreshold =  20;
int highThreshold = 20;

int channels[] = {0, 1};    // HUE & SATURATION

float h_range[] = {0, 179};
float s_range[] = {0, 255};

const float *ranges[] = {h_range, s_range};


Mat capturedFrame, flippedFrame, grayScaleFrame, hsvImage, hueImage, mask, backProjectedImage, grayForContour;
std::vector<    std::vector<cv::Point>   > contours;

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
     CascadeClassifier classifier;
     classifier.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");


VideoCapture captureDevice;
captureDevice.open(0);


namedWindow("Webcam Feed");


while(true){
    captureDevice >> capturedFrame;
    flip(capturedFrame, flippedFrame, 1);

    // gray scale for face detection
    cvtColor(flippedFrame, grayScaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayScaleFrame, grayScaleFrame);

    // hsv image conversion
    cvtColor(flippedFrame, hsvImage, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // separate only Hue channel to be used for the Histogram  in back projection
    hueImage.create(hsvImage.size(), hsvImage.depth());
    int ch[] = {0,0};
    mixChannels(&hsvImage, 1, &hueImage, 1, ch, 1);

    std::vector<Rect> faces;  // to store the face found

    //find faces and store them in the vector array
    classifier.detectMultiScale(grayScaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,  Size(30, 30) );

    if ( faces.size() > 0 ){
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){ 


            // /* BEGINNING BACKPROJECTION WITH FOREHEAD AS REGION OF INTERST */
            float topLeft_X = faces[i].x + faces[i].width/ 4;
            float topLeft_Y = faces[i].y + faces[i].height / 16;

            float bottomRight_X = topLeft_X + faces[i].width / 2;
            float bottomRight_Y = topLeft_Y + faces[i].height/6;

            Point roiPt1(  topLeft_X, topLeft_Y );
            Point roiPt2( bottomRight_X, bottomRight_Y  );

            Mat faceROI = flippedFrame(cv::Rect( topLeft_X , topLeft_Y, bottomRight_X - topLeft_X, bottomRight_Y - topLeft_Y  ));
            // namedWindow("ROI");
            // imshow("ROI", faceROI);

            //draw the rectangle of the region of interst
            rectangle(flippedFrame, roiPt1, roiPt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8, 0);


            //convert the forehead ROI to hsv
            Mat roiHSV;
            cvtColor(faceROI, roiHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

            // Get a histogram of the HSV of the ROI
            MatND roiHist = getHistogram(roiHSV); 
            normalize(roiHist, roiHist, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());                

            // now calculate a backprojection of the hue image
            calcBackProject(&hsvImage, 1, channels, roiHist, backProjectedImage, ranges, 1, true);
            /* ENDING NEW BACKPROJECTION ATTEMPT */


            // Threshold the back projected image
            Mat final;

            /* 
                APPLY GAUSSIAN FILTER BEFORE THRESHOLDING with OTSU
            */
            Mat blur;
            GaussianBlur(backProjectedImage, blur, Size(5, 5),0);
            threshold(blur, final, 0,255,THRESH_BINARY+THRESH_OTSU);

            // opening
            // erode(final, final, MORPH_RECT);
            // dilate(final, final, MORPH_RECT);


            //show the backprojected image
            // namedWindow("Back Projection");
            // imshow("Back Projection", backProjectedImage);

            namedWindow("Threshold Image after Back Projection");
            imshow("Threshold Image after Back Projection", final);


            //Drawing the rectangle around the found face
            Point facePt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            Point facePt2( faces[i].x, faces[i].y );
            rectangle(flippedFrame, facePt1, facePt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);

        }
    }

    imshow("Webcam Feed", flippedFrame);        

    if (waitKey(10) == 27){
        break;
    }

}   

return 0;
```

}

```
// Get a histogram of the forehead ROI using the hue and saturation only
MatND getHistogram(Mat image){
    MatND hist;
    int h_bins = 30;
    int s_bins = 32;
    int histSize[] = {h_bins, s_bins};
    cv::calcHist(&image, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 2, histSize, ranges);
    return hist;
}
```

And here's the result I have now:

[image: result]

Comment: What about using this approach:
http://razibdeb.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/skin-detection-in-c-using-opencv/ 

?

Comment: @GilLevi This approach is working with fixed thresholds and thus is very inflexible in my opinion.

Comment: @Stralo Have you tried to vary the bin sizes of your histogram? There is an opencv tutorial about backprojection([link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html)) and they seem to use other histogram settings.

Comment: @GilLevi - Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried that and it works quite well for my friends but not well on my black skin (I don't get large detected areas. It looks quite like my result). So I figured a good way to get it working well regardless of race would be to use the forehead area of the person.

Comment: @AquilaRapax - I followed that tutorial, actually. But they mention that one can obtain better values by using both the hue and saturation channels instead of only the hue channel used in the tutorial code, and I use both in mine. I'm pretty satisfied with the backprojection but I can't figure out a way to get one solid skin area. I think I could use floodfill to improve it but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: @Stralo Hmm, floodfill should be possible. Maybe you could combine this with an contour detector to find head contours and then use the opencv masked floodfill method.

Comment: @AquilaRapax - When I tried finding and drawing contours, the result looked very bad since the thresholded image has several small blobs.

Comment: @Stralo Did you try a median filter instead of gaussian blurring? Depending of the kernel size it erases small blobs but closes little holes. Or you could try out the denoising-methods opencv provides to erase the little spots.

Comment: @AquilaRapax - Median filtering with a kernel size of 9 worked great. I've been able to remove a lot of the noise in the room and now the only white regions are on my skin. Now I have to join the small white regions on my face and hand to form single large ones. What do you think would be a good way to create a mask to test the opencv floodfill method?

Comment: @Stralo Well, my first idea was to use the closing operator exentsively, but this would be very time-expensive.
As an alternative you could try to use the watershed algorithm using your found regions as starting labels to segment your image and get the contours. Unfortiunately i can't tell you exactly if it works or how you have to parametrize it, but you can read more about it [here](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html).